# How to enable the dropdown above the text editor in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

For some reason I've lost the dropdownbox above the text editor. The one that lists all methods, variables and properties in a class. And it makes me go crazy when I browse larger classes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe it is easier to enable "Navigation bar" option under "Tools->Options->Text Editor->[The language that you using]->General]

Comment: I actually wanted to hide that, so your answer has helped me anyway. Thanks from the future.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried resetting the interface?

1. from the command line run devenv.exe /resetsettings

2.. From Visual Studio

1. On the Tools menu, click Import and Export Settings.
2. On the Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard page, click Reset all settings and then click Next.
3. If you want to save your current settings combination, click Yes, save my current settings, specify a file name, and then click Next.

   —or—

   If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings, and then click Next. This option does not delete default settings, which will still be available the next time you use the wizard.
4. In Which collection of settings do you want to reset to, select a settings collection from the list.
5. Click Finish.

The Reset Complete page alerts you to any problems encountered during the reset.

Comment: This will solve the problem, in the same way that a nuclear detonation will remove an unsightly smudge. Better to use Robert's answer.